# No information available about transaction

Tags: transactions

I transferred all of my 0.0105 BTC in one address to “1Px92t3MBmZcMfomZmt2BKqaaWHRp2y7fQ” through Bitcoin Core. There are two transaction records as following:
[image]
Details are:

> Status: 9 confirmations
>    > Date: 2016/12/3 19:30
>    > Debit: -0.01036619 BTC
>    > Net amount: -0.01036619 BTC
>    > Transaction ID:
>   e71a265559886a784b242a77d952f58821deada04c547d26b61032ee4f8f5360
>    > Output index: 0
>
> Status: 10 confirmations, broadcast through 6 node(s) 
>    > Date: 2016/12/3 19:19 
>    > To: huobi 1Px92t3MBmZcMfomZmt2BKqaaWHRp2y7fQ (watch-only) 
>    > Debit: -0.01036619 BTC 
>    > Credit: 0.01036619 BTC 
>    > Total debit: -0.01036619 BTC 
>    > Total credit: 0.01036619 BTC 
>    > Transaction fee: -0.00013381 BTC 
>    > Net amount: -0.00013381 BTC 
>    > Transaction ID:
>   9ff577cea7b86667eaea93084b4fb7ed75a5ed6d14bdc6e0557ca8fdc55efb82 
>    > Output index: 0

Two questions:

**FIRST
Why there two transaction records and one of them with type “Payment to yourself”? My balance is 0 now.**

SECOND
getrawtransaction

> 9ff577cea7b86667eaea93084b4fb7ed75a5ed6d14bdc6e0557ca8fdc55efb82 1

results: No information available about transaction (code -5)

> What does the transaction
>   9ff577cea7b86667eaea93084b4fb7ed75a5ed6d14bdc6e0557ca8fdc55efb82
>   represented?

Answer (score 1):

looking at [blockchain.info](https://blockchain.info/address/1Px92t3MBmZcMfomZmt2BKqaaWHRp2y7fQ), your first spent to this address was done at 2016-DEC-03 11:19:29 CET, amount was 0.01036619 BTC. This is what is shown in your picture above. You can look at the raw TX here: [9ff577ce...c55efb82](https://blockchain.info/de/rawtx/9ff577cea7b86667eaea93084b4fb7ed75a5ed6d14bdc6e0557ca8fdc55efb82)
Later on there was a second TX: [e71a26555...f8f5360](https://blockchain.info/rawtx/e71a265559886a784b242a77d952f58821deada04c547d26b61032ee4f8f5360)
Both TX are confirmed. All good.
Not sure if I got your question right, on the payment to yourself. Usually if you spend bitcoins, they come from UTXOs, and if a value doesn't exist, the wallet will try to combine several UTXOs to near the desired value. The remainings go back into your wallet. It is like buying something for 9 Euros, you pay with a ten Euro bill, and get 1 Euro back to your wallet.

Comment: Also, `getrawtransaction` only works for unconfirmed transactions unless you run in `txindex` mode. Use `gettransaction` instead, which requests wallet info about a transaction rather than node information.

Comment: Thx for your answer. Actually I had 0.0105 BTC in the account 19CtzwxLnkptTHp49BRVdvzVjxtYDkMvph, and I made a transfer to spend all of the 0.0105 BTC to 1Px92t3MBmZcMfomZmt2BKqaaWHRp2y7fQ. There should not be any remains to be paid back. If there is a payment to myself, I should not get a zero balance.